# PHP: GD Library: Increase font size in ImageString function

Tags: php, gd

I have the following block of code which will output a captcha image

```
 $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg("captcha.jpg"); 
 $rand = _generateRandom(3);
 $_SESSION['captcha'] = $rand;
 ImageString($im, 5, 2, 2, $rand[0]." ".$rand[1]." ".$rand[2]." ", ImageColorAllocate ($im, 23, 85, 160));
```

Now I want to increase the font size. I have used the second parameter as 5. I know that we can use from 1 to 5 only. But I want to increase the \font size a bit more. Also I want to change the font also to some other like Arial or Verdana.

How to do that?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you'd be better off using [`imagettftext`](http://php.net/imagettftext):

```
array imagettftext ( resource $image , float $size , float $angle , int $x , int $y , int $color , string $fontfile , string $text )
```

Comment: Just thought I'd add that if using windows font files can be found in directory C:\Windows\Fonts\

Answer (score 2):

Another quick option is to increase the size of the image, in your html code.  So, if your captcha.php file renders a 50px wide image, show it at 100px wide. It's not ideal but it's a quick fix.

```
<img src="captcha.php" width="100">
```

Comment: It's a solution, but older browser might and will mess up on enlargement and the image (which is a captcha) will not be 100% readable as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`imagettftext()`](http://php.net/imagettftext) function.

```
$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg("captcha.jpg"); 
 $rand = _generateRandom(3);
 $_SESSION['captcha'] = $rand;
 ImageString($im, $size, 0, 2, 2, ImageColorAllocate ($im, 23, 85, 160), $fontfile, $rand[0]." ".$rand[1]." ".$rand[2]." ");
```

where `$size` is the font size, and `$fontfile` is a file containing a TTF font. For more usage information, see the PHP manual entry (linked above).